# Django AuthenticationForm required fields

Tags: python, django

I need to add `required` class to a div element to render the fields of `AuthenticationForm`. But for a reason I can't understand, inside the template, `form.password.required` does not evaluate to True:

```
<div class="field {% if form.password.required %}required{% endif %}">
 {{ form.password.label_tag }}
 {{ form.password }}           
</div>
```

Problem is, when I instantiate a form manually

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
>>> f = AuthenticationForm(None, {"password": "foo", "username":"bar"})
>>> f.is_valid()
>>> f.fields["password"].required # is true
```

Why isn't it true in the template ?

Comment: Have you tried simply doing `{{form.password.required}}` and seeing what it is pushing to the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.password` gives you a [BoundField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField) and not the password field itself, you need to use the `field` attribute of that `BoundField` to access the field and it's attributes

```
<div class="field {% if form.password.field.required %}required{% endif %}">
```